# Android app error only on older emulator

Tags: android

I'm currently devoping an Android app, and whilst every thing is working fine on a Jelly Bean emulator I'm getting the following error on a 2.2 emulator:

```
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.iagrams.util.MyAdapter.getView(MyAapter.java:20)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:115)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  ... 36 more
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x2
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2036)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1834)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:285)
10-11 22:26:35.853: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  ... 40 more
```

As far as I'm aware, I'm not using any Jelly Bean specific features and don't know what I'm getting the error. I do have a custom Adapter but I don't do much with it, I only change a couple of text view's.

Comment: Can you post the XML layout you are inflating ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Adapter for something like this:

```
public class MethodAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Method> {

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MethodAdapter(Context context, int layout, int field, ArrayList<Method> methodsList) {
        super(context, layout, field, methodsList);
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER);
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView bellName;
        TextView bellType;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_item_layout, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.bellName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.bellName);
            holder.bellType = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.bellType);
                convertView.addTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }

        Method m = getItem(position);

        holder.bellName.setText(m.getName());
        holder.bellType.setText(m.getSuffix());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Ps.: I didn't compiled this code. Check it first....

Comment: On line 53, change:
android:layout_weight="1.0"
to
android:layout_weight="1"

Comment: Can you post the code of your list or the adapter ? And the layout of the list item.

Comment: This adapter is not very well implemented. You should use ViewHolder pattern and also verify if convertView is not null before every time recreate the view. I suggest you to put a breakpoint inside your adapter, because it looks like there is a problem on this class.

Comment: The first error occurs on line 20. When I call super.getView(...)

Comment: You don't need this line. I'm editing the answer with a suggestion for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the ViewHolder pattern, but I thought why bother if it was correctly working. Plus with out reusing views the list were drawn quite fast.

Comment: Thanks for the code, however this still does n't work. I still get an error when trying to inflate the convert view. I'll try and modify my XML layout file to see if it works.

Comment: The problem is to do with the xml margins. I've deleted then and changed the button width and height to wrap_content and now its working. Thanks for your help.